# How to disable Jquery Waypoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I have the [template](http://www.preview.webuza.com/?theme=advisa). All I want - to kill JQ Waypoints before they kill my conversion (I really HATE waypoints, as ~85% of Western Europe).

When I try to delete jquery.waypoints.js — content still not appears. What I need to do, what css class I need to change to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to remove the functions in .loader.js, there's a number of lines of them:

```
$('CLASS-OR-ID').waypoint(function() {
```